# Bash Script Argument Containing Spaces Not Working

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a bash noob and can't figure out how to use a string containing spaces in a bash argument. Here's the function giving me problems...

```
handle_arguments() {

ARGUMENTS=($@);

for i in ${ARGUMENTS[@]}
    do

        INDEX=`expr index "$i" =`;

        case $i in
            --projectslug*)
                PROJECT_SLUG=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --sitename*)
                SITE_NAME=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --build*)
                BUILD_TYPE=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --dbname*)
                DB_NAME=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --mysqlun*)
                MYSQL_UN=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --mysqlpw*)
                MYSQL_PW=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --dbfilename*)
                DB_FILE_NAME=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --search*)
                DB_SR_SEARCH=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            --replace*)
                DB_SR_REPLACE=${i:INDEX};
            ;;
            *)
                echo -e "${RED}$i is not recognized as an argument.${NC}\n";
            ;;
        esac
done;

if [[ -z $DB_NAME ]];
    then
        DB_NAME=$PROJECT_SLUG;
fi
}
```

The command I run is...

```
$ source wpautobuild.sh; wp_auto_build --projectslug=abctest1 --sitename="ABC TEST 1"
```

I've been troubleshooting this for hours and everything I'm finding is telling me to wrap `$@` in `ARGUMENTS=($@);` with double quotes so it's `ARGUMENTS=("$@");` but that does not work.

I've also tried adding double quotes to `SITE_NAME=${i:INDEX};` to be `SITE_NAME="${i:INDEX}";` but also with no luck.

One article suggested escaping spaces in the command like this...

```
$ source wpautobuild.sh; wp_auto_build --projectslug=abctest1 --sitename="ABC\ TEST\ 1"
```

...and that did not work either.

*Note: The `handle_arguments()` function is run in the `wp_auto_build()` function which is being called in the command.*

I'm totally stuck and appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote `$@` for it to preserve spaces. Unquoted `$@` serves no purpose, as it is identical to unquoted `$*`.

```
ARGUMENTS=("$@")
```

You subsequently need to quote `${ARGUMENTS[@]}` for the same reason

```
for i in "${ARGUMENTS[@]}"
```

though there is no need for `ARGUMENTS` at all; you can iterate over `"$@"` directly.

```
for i in "$@"
```

Comment: Got it working now. There was just one more place in the other function where called the wp_auto_build() function that I also needed to quote `handle_arguments "$@";'. Thanks for the help!